# how do I keep a formula in a particular cell when I add rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have created a macro in an Excel 16 worksheet which adds a new row at row 6 of a worksheet. In this row I add my latest payslip information with earlier entries listed from row 7 downwards. 
I want to add a formula in G6 that equals (C6-(D6+E6+F6)) and I want this formula to stay in G6. I thought it would be:
=SUM($C$6-(D$6$+E$6$+F$6$)) but the formula moves down to G7 and doesn't stay in cell C6.

Also, when the new row is added at row 6 columns A-G convert my entries to A (date) and B-G (dollar value) but columns H and I are simply the number of hours recorded for overtime and tea allowance (these columns I have set to general) but when I enter 1 or 2 excel converts to $1.00 or $2.00 etc..Why does excel recognize columns A as date and B-G as dollar values but not H and I as general numbers?

Many, many thanks for your help, I am a keen excel user learning by online tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a new row at row 6, the existing row 6 moves down and becomes row 7. If you want to keep the existing row in place, add a row below the existing row.

If you format your data to be an Excel Table object (using Insert > Table), then formatting and formulas will be applied to all new and inserted rows.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, thanks so much for the quick response! I'm not sure if I have explained myself that well but I add the blank row at the top so that when I add the latest payslip, it stays on top in chronological order. I want it to then move down and row 6 to be blank again ready for the next payslip information to be added. I have not used Tables yet in Excel, but will look into that now...many thanks!

Comment: Data should flow from top to bottom, left to right. Adding new data at the top is not good practice, since it causes things to shift down, as you have experienced. Add new data at the bottom. You can have formulas for totals at the top of the data. Freeze panes or split the screen so you can see the top of the sheet and the bottom of the data entry table at the same time.